# What is the correct way to say "Unknown music from the South" or "Unknown musicians from the South" in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, music

I'm about to publish a series of electronic music releases from three up-and-coming Australian producers/musicians. I thought I'd name the series as a word play or reference to "Terra Australis Incognita" but replacing Terra with either Music or Musicians.

**"Unknown music from the South" or "Unknown musicians from the South".**

What would be the correct way to write this? I came up with:

- Musica Australis Incognita
- Musicus Australis Incognita

Answer (score 7):

*Musica Australis Incognita* is correct and I recommend using it.

*Musicus Australis Incognita* is not quite.
If you want a single musician, the last word has to be *incognitus* because it has to be the same masculine gender as *musicus*.

If you want multiple musicians, the plural looks even more different: *Musici Australes Incogniti*.

The wordplay loses power when the difference grows, so I suggest the first option with "music".

Comment: Thanks for a swift reply Joonas, much appreciated!

Comment: @SethBraddock You're welcome! If you like the answer, you can vote it up by clicking the little arrow at the top left of the answer. Below the score thing there's a little green checkmark you can give to one answer to indicate that you got what you were looking for. Our [tour] tells more about the functionalities.